# Probability of getting one correct multiple choice question out of 2 with different number of choices?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Say you have two questions, one with 5 choices and one with 6 (only 1 choice each question is correct). What is the probability of getting **Exactly** one question correct out of the two. I didn't specify if it is the one with 5 choices or the one with 6.
I know that getting both correct would be 1/5 * 1/6. and if both had the same number of choices (say 4) getting only one correct would be 1/4 * 3/4. but how do I approach the above problem? Thanks

Comment: The probability of getting $0$ right is $\frac45\cdot\frac56$. The probability of getting $2$ right is $\frac15\cdot\frac16$. How do you finish the problem from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 5x6 ways to pick two answers. There are 5 ways to pick the first right and the second wrong, and 4 ways to pick the first wrong and the second right, that’s nine ways to get exactly one right. The chances are 9 in 30 or 3 in 10.

You could also count 4x5 ways to get both wrong, 1 way to get both right, and the 30-20-1 = 9 remaining ways are exactly one right.